# How do i properly install ubuntu on a pc with ubuntu already on it?

Tags: lubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my pc currently. I bought a USB flash drive and did the installation instructions from the Ubuntu website. Just to let you know, I did install the Ubuntu OS from a windows 7 PC. So. I plugged the USB flash drive into the PC I wanted it on, started it, then I opened the boot list. Wasn't there so I restarted my computer. I went to the boot list and then it showed up. I selected it and a page shows up after about 30 seconds that showed the Ubuntu install list. I have tried "try Ubuntu before installing" and "install Ubuntu". I hit " install Ubuntu " because they weren't working. So I left Ubuntu to install. I come back 24 hours later. And it is still showing the same screen! Like, what is going on. I need a computer that can install programs in the next couple of days. Should I try Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu? Or can you guys help me out?

UPDATE: Here is what happens when I press Install Ubuntu

[image]

When I press Install Ubuntu, it freezes, and shows that weird pixley sliver at the top of the screen.

I'll update more if it does anything else.

Comment: Are you sure that the program on the windows 7 comp created the install media correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can tell you from my personal experience, Lubuntu is WAY easier to handle, a lot smoother and a lot faster in comparison to Ubuntu. It's also more similar to Windows, so you won't have much problems maneuvering. Also, how about you try making a Live CD/DVD and booting from that? It's usually a faster option.

Comment: Ok. I asked about lubuntu because I have 3 other computers in my family that run lubuntu. There only reason I wanted lubuntu add a last resort is because of its software center. I don't think it has the same packages as the Ubuntu software center.

Comment: @VoyagerLinuxGamer Lubuntu has a program in its' software center to add Ubuntu Software Center, and I think it works. Try it out. Not to mention, every(at least most) of Ubuntu programs work with Lubuntu, because Lubuntu runs on a similar code, if not even the same(with the exception of, of course, Unity, and some software that comes with Ubuntu)

Comment: Ok. I will look into that.

Comment: Lubuntu software center does not have some of the paid apps in the ubuntu software center. You can install the software center if you really want to. Or if you really wanted to you could install lubuntu software center in ubuntu with unity if you really wanted to. Although the software center that comes with unity uses more system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you click the Install button and the click registers, it flaked out on me and I had to click it 2 or 3 times when I did my latest install (just about 2 days ago).

Comment: Ok. I'll try that.